# Google Script ImportRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a Worksheet that is populated with a bunch of people with their info on it. I need to take three cells from a row in this file an place them in 3 consecutive cells in another spreadsheet. I know this can be done with the =ImportRange line in the cells, however I have hundreds of sheets to do and was looking for a way to automate this process.

I have attempted the following

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var menuEntries = [ {name: "Do the thing", functionName:"updateVerified"} ];
      ss.addMenu("Move Values",menuEntries);// custom menu
    }

    function updateVerified() {
       var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MasterSheetID').getSheetByName('Sheet2');            
       var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            

       var data = sheet1.getRange("B2:J2").getValues();
       sheet2.getRange("b4:d4").setValues(data);
    }
```

this returns an error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

even though there is data in the range provided.

Comment: Is this in a script that's tied to a spreadsheet or is it a standalone script?

Comment: It is a script that I am running from the destination spreadsheet

Comment: Is 'MasterSheetID' a placeholder for the actual id? What happens when you debug the script, do sheet1 and sheet2 have values?

Comment: Yes, I had the actual master id in the code. I got an error message stated above and no changes were made. Yes both sheets had data in them. All of that said I figured out what I was doing after I got my head around the way google scripts works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you the owner of the Master Spreadsheet? If not then make sure you have the access rights for it..

And also I noticed, you are getting the values of range "B2:J2" and then setting it on range "B4:D4", which will also throw an error, because both the range should have equal number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I ended up finding my own solution to the problem.